# Ruby on Rails - Has_many, Mass Assignment issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

I'm using rails 3.2.3 and am having issues with mass assignement.

I have a Hotel model and a Hphoto model (integrated with paperclip)

I have tried almost everything and still get mass-assignement error.

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: hphoto
```

Please take a look.

Hotel model

```
has_many :hphotos, :dependent=>:destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for <other models>, :hphotos
attr_accessible: <other attributes>, :hphoto_attributes
```

Hphoto model

```
belongs_to :hotel
has_attached_file :photo,
:path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
:url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename"

attr_accessible :hphoto_attributes

validates_attachment_presence :photo
validates_attachment_size :photo, :less_than => 2.megabytes
validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type=> ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']
```

My hotel controller:

```
def new
    @hotel = Hotel.new
    @hotel.hphotos.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.json { render :json => @hotel }
    end
  end

def create
    @hotel = Hotel.new(params[:hotel])
    <original scaffold code>
end
```

Thanks for your thoughts

Comment: Where is it throwing the problem?

Comment: When i submit the form. "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: hphoto"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement must use the plural:

```
attr_accessible: <other attributes>, :hphotos_attributes
```

On Rails 3.2.3 my erb looks like this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :hphotos, @hotel.hphotos do |photo_form| %>  
    <%= photo_form.label :size %>  
    <%= photo_form.text_field :size %>  
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the `:hphotos_attributes`. I was missing the plural form, also, on my view, I had `f.fields_for :hphoto` and I needed to put `:hphotos`. Thanks for your input. Regards.